# Pass params to RMarkdown from Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I've been writing Shiny apps for clients at work and they usually involve creating standardized reports in RMarkdown using the data in the app. I've noticed something that seems like strange behavior by `downloadHandler` when passing `params`, and I'm hoping someone can explain what is going on to me.

Strange behavior: If I define `params` in the `rmarkdown::render()` function, it doesn't get passed to RMarkdown. However, if I define it in the `content` function but outside `render()` it gets passed properly to the .Rmd file.

Below is a reproducible example of what I am describing. It works as written, but if you switch the comment from line 21 to line 19 (which is how I would think it should be), then the `params` don't get passed. Can someone please explain why?

Thank you.

**app.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)

rm(list = ls())

# Sample data to pass as params
a <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = runif(10))

ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Passing params to downloadHandler Question"),
   sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(downloadLink(outputId = "download")),
                 mainPanel())
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   output$download <- downloadHandler(filename = "file.html",
                                      content = function(file) {
# Doesn't work if comment is switched from line 21 to line 19, but why?
                                        params  <- list(a = a) 
                                        out <- rmarkdown::render(input = "params.Rmd"
                                                                 #,params = list(a = a)
                                                                 )
                                        file.copy(out,file)
                                      })
   }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**params.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

``` {r}
params$a
```
````

Comment: You haven't defined `params` in your RMD, which is why they are not being passed. It works when you define `params` from your content function because the RMD is looking to the parent environment.

Comment: Notice how parameters are declared in the YAML block on R Studio''s documentation http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html You need to esit your RMD appropriately

Comment: Ah, that explains it. I had a hunch that it was related to the environment. Thanks.